# Erro em fórmula com OU

Tags: microsoft-excel

Alguma razão para isto não funcionar?

Eu pretendo que ele conte quantas situações existem dentro de um ou outro critério.

Tanto esta fórmula:

```
=CONTAR.SE.S(E:E;">120";E:E;"<139" OU F:F;">80";F:F;"<89")
```

Como esta:

```
=CONTAR.SE.S((E:E;">120";E:E;"<139")OU(F:F;">80";F:F;"<89"))
```

Não funciona.

Traduzindo melhor o que pretendo é assim:
Eu quero o valor total de uma tabela em que os valor da coluna E se encontram entre 120 e 139 ou entao que na coluna F os valores se encontrem entre 80 e 89.
Caso essa linha tenha as duas situações como verdadeiras apenas vai contar uma.

Tipo um if, se condicao 1=verdadeiro entao conta 1 passa para o proximo caso contrario verifica a condicao 2 e se esta for verdadeira conta 1 e passa para o proximo

Comment: Apaguei minha resposta pois vi que ela não atendia a sua pergunta. Entretanto o ideal seria que você adicionasse as informações que você me passou à sua pergunta explicando um pouco melhor qual é o seu objetivo final. Se você quiser eu colo aqui o seu último comentário.

Comment: Só um detalhe que eu acabei repetindo a coluna `E` na minha resposta, o _certo_ seria `=CONTAR.SE.S(E:E;">120";E:E;"<139")+CONTAR.SE.S(F:F;">80";F:F;"<89")`, entretanto acho que o que você quer é que a condição seja feita linha a linha, correto? Ou seja, se E1 atender a condição não precisa verificar a condição no F1.

Comment: Exactamente @math

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Atenção**: Não sei se isso se deve à versão do Excel, mas no meu Excel
>   em Português (versão 14.0.7149.5000 32 bits do Office 2010) *não
>   existe* uma função chamada `CONTAR.SE.S`. A função que existe no meu
>   Excel é `CONT.SES` (e por isso eu a uso no exemplo). Ainda assim,
>   supondo que a sua função esteja com o nome correto, a resposta
>   continua válida (basta trocar o nome da função).

A função [CONT.SES](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-CONTSES-53c4dc8e-0e5b-4e32-93df-9ca5e7da89ed?ui=pt-BR&rs=pt-BR&ad=BR), de contagem com múltiplos critérios, permite que você faça a contagem usando múltiplis critérios e múltiplos intervalos. Então, pra ter o cálculo que você deseja bastan fazer três contagens:

1. Conte os valores na coluna E que estejam dentro dos intervalos de interesse dessa coluna
2. Conte os valores na coluna F que estejam dentro dos intervalos de interesse dessa coluna
3. Conte os valores *em ambas colunas* que estejam dentro dos seus respectivos intervalos.

Se você somar os valores de (1) e (2), ele vai estar quase sempre certo, exceto quando ocorrerem as exceções que você menciona (os valores de ambas as colunas E e F em uma determinada linha serem ambos aceitos). Essas exceções são contabilizadas por (3), então basta subtrair esse valor da soma anterior.

Por exemplo:

```
=CONT.SES(E:E;">120";E:E;"<139")+CONT.SES(F:F;">80";F:F;"<89")-CONT.SES(E:E;">120";E:E;"<139";F:F;">80";F:F;"<89")
```

Pra evitar que os valores fiquem fixos na fórmula, talvez você deseje configurar outras células com esses valores (por exemplo, as células I1, J1, K1 e L1). Nesse caso, faça a fórmula assim:

```
=CONT.SES(E:E;">"&I1;E:E;"<"&J1)+CONT.SES(F:F;">"&K1;F:F;"<"&L1)-CONT.SES(E:E;">"&I1;E:E;"<"&J1;F:F;">"&K1;F:F;"<"&L1)
```

Eis um exemplo de planilha (que você poderia ter fornecido - facilitiaria enormemente a vida de quem fosse lhe ajudar), com o resultado (as células "Em E", "Em F" e "Em E e F" contém as fórmulas parciais para demonstrar os resultados em cada item anteriormente exposto). A linha indicada pela seta em vermelho é a única em que as condições são satisfeitas nas duas colunas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Já foram apresentadas várias respostas, mas fica aqui uma alternativa mais concisa para o que desejas obter.

```
=SOMA(SE((E:E>120)*(E:E<139)+(F:F>80)*(F:F<89);1;0))
```

Um pormenor **bastante** importante: Quando acabares de inserir esta fórmula, necessitas de pressionar <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Caso não o faças a fórmula não irá funcionar.

Comment: Fantástica resposta! Merece mais votos (e eu diria até que merece ser a resposta aceita!). :) Sugestão: edite a resposta para indicar ao leitor que se trata do uso de uma fórmula matricial. Seria bom também indicar algum site para leitura complementar sobre o assunto. Por exemplo, esse: http://gurudoexcel.com/blog/introducao-a-formulas-matriciais/

Comment: @LuizVieira, mais logovou actualizar a resposta para incluir as tuas sugestões. Obrigado

Answer (score -2):

A sintaxe da função `OU` está errada. Ela funciona da seguinte maneira:

```
OU(condição1, condição2,...,condiçãoN)
```

Se qualquer uma das condições dentro da função forem verdadeiras, ele retorna verdadeiro.

Veja [este artigo](http://excelb2b.com/2013/11/05/como-usar-funcao-ou-e-funcao-se-juntas/) sobre o uso das funções `OU` e `SE` juntas, e leia a documentação da função `OU` [aqui](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-OU-b798d26a-f60c-4a7e-b3a3-4dbbedf30d90?ui=pt-BR&rs=pt-BR&ad=BR)

Comment: Na verdade isso responde apenas parte da pergunta, o que ele quer no final das contas é usar o `OU()` dentro do `CONTAR.SE.E()` pois a função em questão apenas usa o `E()` para seus parâmetros.